# Can't create solr core : _version_ field must exist in schema and be searchable and retrievable and not multiValued

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

Full error :

```
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'product_v2': Unable to create core [product_v2] Caused by: _version_ field must exist in schema and be searchable (indexed or docValues) and retrievable(stored or docValues) and not multiValued (_version_ is multiValued
```

Schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="product_v2" version="1.5">

    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

    <!-- points to the root document of a block of nested documents. Required for nested
       document support, may be removed otherwise
    -->
    <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

    <!-- Only remove the "id" field if you have a very good reason to. While not strictly
      required, it is highly recommended. A <uniqueKey> is present in almost all Solr
      installations. See the <uniqueKey> declaration below where <uniqueKey> is set to "id".
    -->
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="sku" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />


    <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness.
         Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
      -->
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
</schema>
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what to do.  As far as I can tell, version is meeting all requirements.  I've used Solr a fair amount in the past without issues but this is my first time using Solrcloud + Zookeeper.

Solr version is 6.3.0

Comment: Did you reload the collection after change the schema ?

Comment: Yes, I reloaded the collection, no issues/messages.  I then try to create the core and it gives the following message.

Comment: The error message says,In the collection "product_v2" the field "_version_" is multivalued. It must be multivalued false

Comment: Can you please provide few more lines from error stacktrace ? (Typically if it has more cause by )

Comment: @AshrafulIslam : In the schema I posted above you can see that the version meets all criteria (I believe)

Comment: @Shubhangi : There is no more information in the logs.  Simply the message I provided and a traceroute.

Comment: Also, wanted to note that under the admin area -> cloud -> tree -> configs are shown as correctly updated.  I am assuming that this means zookeeper has correct files

Comment: @hendr1x, what happens if you remove  multiValued="false" for _version_ field definition ?

Comment: No change...I got things working kinda...will post an answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Alright...so I don't have a exact answer but I did move past this problem so I figured I would provide info on things I did to get things working.

1) I decided to just get the example working and then peel away functionality

2) I did not create the solr folders for the collection core and assign proper ownership for files (for me it was in /usr/local/solr/server/solr)...I think not having a core.properties files was messing things up.

3) I didn't delete config files from solr directory after uploading to zookeeper (don't think this matters but wanted to note)

4) I didn't restart solr, I was just reloading using the API